# How can I solve this 2-order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I've given the following PDE:

$$u_t=\dfrac{1}{2}u_{xx}-\dfrac{1}{10}u+1-x$$
with
$$u(t,0)=0, \quad u_x(t,1)=0, \quad u(0,x)=20x(1-x).$$

I know how to use separation of variable methods and tried to use the substitution $u(t,x)=v(x)+w(t,x)$ but neither of them works.

Could someone give me some hints on how to solve this equation system analytically?

Comment: If you take $\mathcal{U}(s,x)=\mathcal{L}\big(u(t,x)\big)$ (where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform) then after applying $\mathcal{L}$ your DE becomes $$\mathcal{U}_{xx}-(2s+1)\mathcal{U}=40x^2+\Big(\frac{2}{s}-40\Big)x-\frac{2}{s}$$ subject to the conditions $$\mathcal{U}(s,0)=0=\mathcal{U}_x(s,1)$$ The above DE can be solved using standard techniques like undetermined coefficients, variation of parameters, etc. Have you considered this approach?

Comment: Could you explain further why the substitution you suggest doesn't work?  I have a feeling that you can find a steady state (your $v(x)$) and substract it to get a homoegeneous problem for $w(t,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$ u_t= a^2 \, u_{xx} - b^2 \, u + 1 - x $$
with $u(0, t)=0, \, u_x(1, t)=0, \, u(x, 0)= c \, x (1-x),$ then let $u(x, t) = w(x, t) + v(x)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
u_{t} &= w_{t} \\
u_{x} &= w_{x} + v_{x} \\
u_{x x} &= w_{x x} + v_{x x}
\end{align}
and
$$ w_{t} = a^2 \, (w_{x x} + v_{x x} ) - b^2 \, (w + v) + 1 - x $$
or
$$ w_{t} = a^2 \, w_{x x} - b^2 \, w + \left( a^2 \, v_{x x} - b^2 \, v + 1 - x \right).$$
Letting
$$ a^2 \, v_{x x} - b^2 \, v + 1 - x = 0, $$
with $v(0) = 0$ and $v_{x}(1) = 0$ then
$$ w_{t} = a^2 \, w_{x x} - b^2 \, w $$
with $ w(0, t) = 0, \, w_{x}(1, t) = 0, \, w(x, 0) = c \, x \, (1-x) - v(x).$
From here,
$$ w(x, t) = e^{- \lambda \, t} \, F(x) $$
which leads to
$$ F^{''} + \left(\frac{\lambda}{a^2} - b^2 \right) \, F = 0 $$
with $F(0) = 0$ and $F^{'}(1) = 0$. This gives
$$ F(x) = B \, \sin\left(\frac{(2 n+1) \, \pi \, x}{2}\right) $$
with $$ \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_{n}}{a^2} - b^2} = \frac{(2 n + 1) \, \pi}{2} $$
or $$ \lambda_{n} = a^2 b^2 + \frac{a^2 \, (2 n +1)^2}{4}. $$
Now,
$$ w(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \, e^{- \lambda_{n} \, t} \, \sin\left(\frac{(2 n+1) \, \pi \, x}{2}\right). $$

Returning to $v(x)$ the differential equation gives the solution
$$ v(x) = A \, \cos\left(\frac{b x}{a} \right) + B \, \sin\left(\frac{b x}{a}\right) + \frac{1 - x}{b^2} $$
with the conditions $v(0) = 0$ and $v^{'}(1) = 0$. This gives
$$ v(x) = \frac{1}{b^3} \, \left( b(1-x) - b \, \cos\left(\frac{b x}{a}\right) + (a \, \sec\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) + b \, \tan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{b x}{a}\right) \right). $$

From here is it a matter of collecting the pieces and finding the Fourier Coefficients.